# Multiple lines in HTTP PUT Body (Inpustream) causes problems

Tags: java, spring, arrays, inputstream, put

I have a method that receives the inputstream via HTTP Put and converts it into byte[] and sends it to another method called verifysignature. I have been having a weird problem with it. The code is all right, but however the message digests don't match. After debugging, I found out it works fine if my inpustream has a single line of text but fails when there are multiple lines.

The request body of Http PUT looks like :

```
{
"Url":"http://live.dev:3000/access_tokens",
"AuthorizationUrl":"http://live.dev:3000/client_access_tokens",
"Cert":"test"
}
```

The method that responds to PUT request:

```
public @ResponseBody Map<String,String> createAuthorizationServer(HttpServletRequest request)throws IOException {
        // This method converts inputstream to byte[]
        byte[] inputStream = toBodyBytes(request.getInputStream());
        X509Certificate signingCert = null;
        //..... stuff
        // Here I am using the byte array
        signingCert = engine.verifySignature(signature,inputStream);
```

This works fine when the payload in request body is something in one line:

```
"test:;sample"
```

But fails when it has a multiple lines, like:

```
"test:;"
"sample"
```

Can someone please throw some light at this?

`toBodyBytes` method for your reference:

```
private static byte[] toBodyBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        final int MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE = 10240;
        byte[] buf = new byte[MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE];
        // protect against OutOfMemoryError in case of  misconfiguration (accidentally filtering uploads)
        int bodySize = read(inputStream, buf, 0, buf.length);
        checkState(bodySize < MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE, "Looking for signature on upload payload?");
        return copyOf(buf, bodySize);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does `toBodyBytes` do?

Comment: It converts inputstream to byte[]. It works fine. I am adding it in the question for your reference

Comment: Ok, now what does `read` do? What does `copyOf` do? Please debug.

Comment: I already debugged, they work fine with single line request bodies. `read` and `copyof` are from guava-16.0.1 and java.utils.Arrays respectively

Comment: They are static methods of which class?

Comment: @Sasanka Panguluri , we are trying to see how you are reading the stream and any possibility of error while reading ( like end of line char and so) . as Sotirios Delimanolis debug you code

Comment: Yup, I understand and appreciate your help. @SotiriosDelimanolis read is from package `com.google.common.io.ByteStreams` and `copyOf` is from `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: I tried to see if alternative methods work and I found a method `getBytes` on the internet that converts inputstream to byte[]. I used it and it works with one line but not multiple lines- in short, same behavior. Here is `getBytes` http://pastebin.com/7YsBrmwe

Comment: if i understood the api document correctly. you are reading 10240 bytes only. if your stream has more bytes then you are not \reading it. you have to loop through it

Comment: Now explains what _fails_ means? A new line character is represented in the bytes, so there will be extra bytes in your `byte[]`.

Comment: Thank you, by saying *fails* I meant it's causing a "message-digest does not match the calculated value" error. 10240 is 10kb and my actual request body can never be more than that. I thought that should work.